# Intermittent memory corruption errors in JNA calls

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, native, jna

We have a very simple requirement of calling a couple of native functions from Java. We are using JNA for making those native calls.

**Edits:** We don't have any custom native code. We are making calls to Linux Kernel C library functions.

We are getting very weird memory corruption errors like

- Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f9b7849fc40
- Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x00007f253c4470f0
- SIGSEGV (0xb)

The program even hangs up some times. These errors are intermittent.

Some standard examples/docs around using structures in JNA calls would be helpful.

---

This is our library wrapper having native functions:

https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw/blob/master/csw-time-client/src/main/scala/csw/time/client/internal/TimeLibrary.java

These are the native models which map to structures in C:

https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw/tree/master/csw-time-client/src/main/scala/csw/time/client/internal/native_models

And this is how we are accessing the library functions:

```
val timeVal = new NTPTimeVal()
TimeLibrary.ntp_gettimex(timeVal)
println(timeVal.tai)
```

You can refer to the TimeServiceImpl.scala for more clarity.

https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw/blob/master/csw-time-client/src/main/scala/csw/time/client/internal/TimeServiceImpl.scala

Could someone tell us what exactly are we doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably error in native code. Can you show it?

Comment: We are making 3 native calls and all are inbuilt in Linux kernel C library code. We haven't written any custom C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reserved fields in [`ntptimeval`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/timex.h#L30) and related structures:

```
struct ntptimeval
{
  struct timeval time;  /* current time (ro) */
  long int maxerror;    /* maximum error (us) (ro) */
  long int esterror;    /* estimated error (us) (ro) */
  long int tai;     /* TAI offset (ro) */

  long int __glibc_reserved1;
  long int __glibc_reserved2;
  long int __glibc_reserved3;
  long int __glibc_reserved4;
};
```

Which you don't have in [your code](https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw/blob/master/csw-time-client/src/main/scala/csw/time/client/internal/native_models/NTPTimeVal.java):

```
public class NTPTimeVal extends Structure {
    public TimeVal time;        /* Current time */
    public Long maxerror;       /* Maximum error */
    public Long esterror;
    public int tai;
}
```

If those reserved fields happen to be used in your `glibc` version, that can explain the heap corruption.

I would also carefully examine the data you get back. If some fields contain strange values, it may mean field size/alignment problem, which can also signal the structure being shorter than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. We had used Linux manpage (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ntp_gettime.3.html) to write the structure fields in our JNA code which turned out to be the source of error.

It seems to be working fine with the new structure. Thank you once again :-)